# Normal Map Artifacts

Tags: uv, normals, baking, normal-map

Im trying to bake a high poly mesh onto a low poly mesh, but it bakes incorrectly, it does it for both blender baking and substance painter, so it's something with the mesh for sure.

[image: the issue]

[image: the models]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yeah, i figured it was my UV, the uv had some intersecting parts, so just had to get some more seams on the mesh, funny how you figure these obvious problems out once you've spent hours trying to figure them out, just to realize your problem after posting it on a forum *sigh*...

Comment: Can you expand on what the solution is other than it was "poorly unwrapped"? You can use the 'edit' link below the answer to add more information. I would also suggest removing anything that isn't relevant to the actual solution.